# How to access property from static method

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

As the title says I am setting a property with the constructor and would like to access the property later as a get function that is static. How would I do this in MATLAB?

```
classdef Wrapper
    
    properties(Access=public)
        dataStruct
    end
    
    methods
    
        function data = Wrapper(filePath)
            if nargin == 1
                data.dataStruct=load(filePath)
            end
            
        end
    end
        
    methods(Static)
        function platPosition = getPlatPosition()
            platPosition = dataStruct.someField
        end
    end
end

--------------------------
import pkg.Wrapper.*
test = Wrapper('sim.mat')
pos = test.getPlatPosition
```

Comment: It is surprising that you want to access a dynamic property from a static method. What is the need to keep the method static ? You can of course pass the object as first argument as Praveen suggested but in this case, what is the difference with a dynamic method ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know MATLAB doesn't have static properties like other OOP languages [[ref]](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/matlab-vs-other-oo-languages.html#buwskub). Only static properties can be used inside the static methods. The closest you can get in MATLAB classes to static property is `Constant` property. The downside is the constant property has to be initialized and is read-only. Inside the static method, You can access read-only/constant property with class name.

```
classdef Wrapper
    
    properties(Constant=true)
        dataStruct=load('\path\to\sim.mat');
    end
    
    methods
        function data = Wrapper()   
            %do something with object
        end
    end
        
    methods(Static=true)
        function platPosition = getPlatPosition()
            platPosition = Wrapper.dataStruct.Fieldname;
        end
    end
end
```

In your case, you could accept object as an input argument of your static method.

```
classdef Wrapper
    
    properties(Access=public)
        dataStruct
    end
    
    methods
    
        function data = Wrapper(filePath)
            if nargin == 1
                data.dataStruct=load(filePath)
            end
            
        end
    end
        
    methods(Static)
        function platPosition = getPlatPosition(obj)
            platPosition = obj.dataStruct.someField
        end
    end
end
--------------------------
import pkg.Wrapper.*
test = Wrapper('sim.mat')
pos = test.getPlatPosition(test);
```